# How to generate a Weibull distribution with inverse transform

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, weibull-distribution, quantiles

Given $X\sim \text{Weibull}(\lambda,k)$, generate samples from the [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) using the [inverse transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

We know $F_X(x) = 1-\text{e}^{-(x/\lambda)^k}$ for $x\ge 0$ with $\lambda,k > 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), replace $F_X(x)$ with $U\sim U(0,1)$, $X$ for $x$, and solve for $X$.

$$\begin{align} U &= 1-\text{e}^{-(X/\lambda)^k} \\
1-U &=\text{e}^{-(X/\lambda)^k} \\
-\text{ln}(1-U) &= \left(\frac{X}{\lambda}\right)^k \\
\left[-\text{ln}(1-U)\right]^{\frac{1}{k}} &= \frac{X}{\lambda} \\
X &= \lambda\left[-\text{ln}(1-U)\right]^{\frac{1}{k}} \quad \quad \square
\end{align}$$

```
% MATLAB 2017a
% Inverse Transform for Weibull distribution
% Parameters
lambda = 1.5;
k = 2;
n = 1000;                             % number of samples to generate

% Generation
U = rand(n,1);                        % U ~ Uniform(0,1)
X = lambda*((-log(1-U)).^(1/k));      % X ~ Weibull(lambda,k)
```